# Print the Navigator attributes in pyppeteer?

Tags: javascript, python, pyppeteer

I want to know what navigator attributes are loaded when my pages load.
Here are some attributes that I should be able to retrieve,
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp.
However, there seems to be more such as:
`window.navigator.webdriver` etc that aren't listed on the above page.
I'd like to be able to print all attributes and values
once my loads.

I've looked around in the docs, but the only references I see are to query selectors for tags.

https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#